# Linear elliptic problems: Are gradient estimates preserved after perturbation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity, perturbation-theory

(This question is a duplicate from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651225/linear-elliptic-problems-are-gradient-estimates-preserved-after-perturbation))

We start with the linear elliptic PDE

$$
-\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)=f \quad\text{in}\ \Omega,\\
u=0 \quad\text{on}\ \partial\Omega
$$
We assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth domain, that $A\in C^\alpha(\overline{\Omega})$ (for some $\alpha>0$) is a symmetric, positive definite matrix-valued function (there is $c_A>0$ such that $A(x)\xi\cdot\xi>c_\alpha|\xi|^2$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and all $x\in\Omega$), and a function $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$.

For some $\delta>0$ and some symmetric $B\in C^\alpha(\overline{\Omega})$, we also look at the perturbed problem

$$
-\operatorname{div}((A+\delta B)\nabla v)=f \quad\text{in}\ \Omega,\\
v=0 \quad\text{on}\ \partial\Omega.
$$

**My question**: If I know, that I have bounds on the gradient of $u$, like

$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C(C_P,|\Omega|,c_\alpha,\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}),
$$

can I conclude something similar for $v$ (for sufficiently small $\delta$), like

$$
\|\nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C(C_P,|\Omega|,c_\alpha,\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)},\delta, \|B\|_{C^\alpha(\overline{\Omega})})?
$$
In these estimates, $C_P$ denotes the Poincare inequality constant.

I tried to prove this estimate via difference quotients and cut-offs but somehow got stuck. If it holds, what technique would you use to prove this? And if it is not possible, why could this estimate fail?

Comment: What method do you use to estimate the gradient for $u$? Is the problem a result of the lack of symmetry in $B$?

Comment: This  will be very hard to say since your assumptions are in general not strong enough to give bounded solution gradients for any matrix $A$ and data $f$ with the stated properties, so you either need to strengthen these accordingly (see e.g. Gilbarg/Trudinger Chapter 8.11) or you need to tell about the particularities of the given $A$ and $f$.

Comment: @sorrymaker symmetry is not the issue for me, I am fine with assuming it (I have updated the question accordingly)

Comment: @Hannes I was thinking of an a priori argument (assuming you have bounds for $u$ do they also hold for $v$) but I have now updated the question to ensure the regularity for $u$

Comment: @Muschkopp But now the assumptions for $B$ are also so strong that your desired estimate follows from the Gilbarg/Trudinger Chapter anyway, no? :-)